# open source faceted search / guided navigation for ecommerce sites with .net apis

Tags: c#, .net, search, full-text-search, facet

i am looking for open source libraries which provide high performance faceted search / guided navigation for ecommerce sites

our ecommerce platform is entirely built on .net and so i would prefer libraries which do provide .net apis

performance is of utmost importance here... i checked out sphinx as well as solr but looking for better options as far as performance goes

as per blogs sphinx takes an average of 5 - 6 seconds to perform the first level of faceted search which is unacceptable in a real ecommerce environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is exactly what you are looking for.

Is a full-fledged search server built using Lucene libs and easily integrable into your .NET application because it has a RESTful API. Comes out-of-the-box with several features such as faceting, caching, scaling, spell-checking, etc.

You can make life easier for your app-to-Solr interaction using the excellent [SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) library.

Comment: oops missed the part where you say you checked out solr, but unsure about what performance issues you ran into. We use Solr on terascale data with no issues whatsoever. Have you checked out Solr scaling & Performance on Lucid Imagination? http://bit.ly/ifnxnO

Comment: hey mikos... thanks for the suggestion... looks like SOLR is the best bet at the moment... +1

Comment: Yes, Solr is perfect for what you're after. If you want to see it in action, check out www.fancydressoutfitters.co.uk. The search and browse experience is all driven through Solr, with main product catalogue data being held in a standard RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at lucene.net it is a very powerful search engine that can be customised for most search related requirements:

http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/