# document content search

Tags: .net, search, document

I've developed a document system that allows my client to upload several types of files: word, pdf, ppt, etc. in a database in which they are stored as binary data. The documents are entered in the database alongside certain metadata such as title, summary, owner, category, etc. Users can search for documents matching words in the titles and summaries. My client wants now users to be able to search the contents of the files. Without using SQL Server full-text search, what other option do I have?  Many thanks!

Comment: Hmm... Make and store an index along the document?

Comment: @khachik Thanks, sorry could you roughly explain be how to do this on binary data types

Comment: how are you going to search in binary data? Does you binary data have a textual representation? Is it searchable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org)?  It is pretty much the de facto indexing engine.  They have a [.net version](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) in incubation as well.

Answer (score 0):

[open source faceted search / guided navigation for ecommerce sites with .net apis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525892/open-source-faceted-search-guided-navigation-for-ecommerce-sites-with-net-apis/4536681#4536681)